# Nested (Chained) query in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I have the following document structure:

***Item: {ItemId (string), Flag (bool), Type ("Item")}***

***SubItem" {ItemId (string), Text (sting), Type ("SubItem")}***

I need to get all Items with *Flag=true* and any of its SubItem Text has a term "term".

I can easily get list of Items if any of its SubItem Text has the term by using DuplicateFiler but how to do filter by Flag? Tried to create BooleanQuery but it's not very good as number of Items is big

Answer (score 0):

I greatly recommend you to take a look into BlockJoinQuery in Lucene. 
Very good start for it - http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/01/searching-relational-content-with.html